# Quarkus 1.2.0 native Build not working with Java 11

Tags: quarkus

I downloaded a default application from https://code.quarkus.io/, changed maven.compiler.source/target to 11, and added a Java 11 feature to org.acme.ExampleResource like `var x = 1`.

Then I started a build using `mvnw package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true`.
In the logs I see:

```
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep] Running Quarkus native-image plugin on GraalVM Version 19.2.1 CE
```

As expected the build now fails with the error message

```
UnsupportedFeatureException: Class initialization of io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl failed
```

Cause is

```
UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/acme/ExampleResource has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0)
```

Why does it use Graal VM 19.2.1 instead of 19.3.1?

If I do a multistage build like described on https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image, the compilation works.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. This only happens when you add -Dquarkus.native.container-runtime=docker, then Quarkus uses native-image plugin  GraalVM Version 19.2.1.
But when you build a native image for your local machine without -D parameter above, it uses the correct GraalVM version.

Comment: Luckily for me, the build for the Docker container is the same as the one for my local (Ubuntu) machine. So I can build locally and use that one in my container.